# Groovy Mapping : Get all the values of a column

Tags: groovy, mapping

I have a json as below and I am trying to get the list of all the "dev" hosts using Groovy.
How can I do that ? I have attached a sample code that I am using currently, but that does not work for obvious reasons. I am new to Groovy.

```
{
  "app1": {
    "dev": [
      "host1",
      "host2"
    ],
    "qa": null,
    "uat": [
      "host11"
    ]
  },
  "app2": {
    "qa": null,
    "stable": null,
    "dev": [
      "host3",
      "host4"
    ]
}
```

CODE:

```
apiResponse = <Code which returns the json as mentioned above>
def parser = new JsonSlurper()
def host_list = parser.parseText(apiResponse)

dev_hosts = host_list[]['dev']

print dev_hosts
```

Expected Result:

```
['host1','host2','host3','host4']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of ways to do it and the best way may depend on knowing some more about the common usage patterns with respect to how many objects are in the top level JSON document etc, but the following does function:

```
String jsonInput = """
{
"app1": {
    "dev": [
        "host1",
        "host2"
    ],
    "qa": null,
    "uat": [
        "host11"
    ]
  },
  "app2": {
      "qa": null,
          "stable": null,
          "dev": [
            "host3",
            "host4"
        ]
    }
}"""

def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonInput)
def results = object.collect { it.value.dev }.flatten()

assert results == ['host1', 'host2', 'host3', 'host4']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dev_hosts = host_list.values().collectMany{it['dev']}
```

edit: OP adjusted the specs: `dev` should be a variable and the lists
need to be flattened (at first level presumably).

Comment: How can I pass 'dev' as a parameter to the command ?

Comment: @SujeetPadhi Answer is updated to new specs